# Creating arrays within structs? Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I compiled this small amount of `C` code and when I run it, I get a segmentation fault.

It stops in the first lines of the `create_index()` function even though I have permission to access the addresses of the pointers. I have no clue what's going on.

#### main.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "hash.h"

int main(void)
{       HTinfo *head;
        create_index(&head);
        return 0;
}
```

#### hash.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "hash.h"

int create_index(HTinfo **head)
{       int i;
        (*head)->empty = 1;
        (*head)->index = malloc(101*sizeof(nodeptr));
        if ((*head)->index == NULL)
            return -1;
        for (i=0; i < 101; i++)
            (*head)->index[i] = NULL;
        return 0;
}
```

#### hash.h

```
typedef struct rc *nodeptr;

typedef struct rc {
    char ln[25];
    char fn[15];
    char city[25];
    char prefecture[3];
    int debt;
    int afm;
    nodeptr next;
} record;

typedef struct ht {
        nodeptr *index;
        char empty;
} HTinfo;
```

Comment: You didn't allocate for `head` (in `main`) nor `*head` (in `create_index`)

Comment: This: `(*head)->empty = 1;' There's no valid memory pointer in `*head` or `head`.

Comment: The error is as the others have said.  It might have been more obvious if you had initialized the value in your main call:  HTinfo *head = NULL.  Without an initial value, in "c", it may be anything...

Comment: You could use some readings about C. Some good reference is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't allocate memory for `head`. Either `malloc` in `main`:

```
HTinfo * head = malloc(sizeof *head);
if(NULL == head) // handle out-of-memory
```

or in `create_index`:

```
*head = malloc(sizeof **head);
if(NULL == *head) // handle out-of-memory
```

Answer (score 1):

**First thing**, when you run into a `segmentation fault`, try to debug your code using a memory debugger like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org). Most of the time, it **will** point out the erroneous code block.

From the code you have posted, it can be seen that you did not allocate any memory for `HTinfo *head` and tried to pass the address (which is invalid) to `create_index()` and then, without any check, you de-referenced it. As the memory location is not valid, this is an ***undefined behavior*** scenario, most likely lead to a *segmentation fault*, just as in your case.

Also, it is a best practice to always initialize a pointer when declared and check the validity of an incoming pointer variable to a function. You should initialize `head` in `main()` with `HTinfo *head = NULL` and might want to add a `NULL` check in the `create_index()` function itself, which will help you detecting passing invalid (NULL) address to the function (in case you forget to allocate memory) and will also prevent your code from crashing. You can use something like

```
if (*head != NULL)
{
     //your code
}
else
{
     //print appropriate error message, return/exit
}
```

Comment: Note that the `*head` check in `create_index()` is not guaranteed to work since the pointer in `main()` is not initialized so it might not be a null pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for mentioning that. I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTinfo *head;
```

In `main()`, you are allocating a pointer to `HTInfo` structure. You could rather allocate the whole structure statically and pass a pointer to `create_index()`

```
int main(void)
{
    HTinfo head;
    create_index(&head);
    // continue ...
    // you should be testing for the return value of create_index()
```

And deal with the pointer in your `create_index()`

```
int create_index(HTinfo *phead)
{
    int i;
    phead->empty = 1;
    phead->index = calloc(101, sizeof(nodeptr));
    if (phead->index == NULL)
        return -1;
    // continue ...
```